# LESS class declared in itself

Tags: css

I am working on a project where I have been seeing this way of declaring classes in LESS. The class is declared again inside itself like in the example below:

```
.user-images {
  // some LESS here
  
  .user-images {
    // some more LESS here
  }
}
```

Initially I thought this was a copy paste mistake but this is regularly used, so it looks intentional. I have also moved the code outside the second declaration but that seems to break everything.

I have always tried to refactor this and remove the second declaration (based only on my opinion that code should be simple to read and understand), but now I am starting to get really curious.

Googling does not seem to help (or I may be searching with the wrong keywords).
Can anyone explain how this works and why would someone use this?

To note is that all the code is written in LESS and compiled to CSS.

Comment: If the code was exactly like this one, then it's adding styles to an element  that wrapped with a parent element and both have the same class, but maybe it as needed to add styles to the child element only, However, this is not a good practice at all

Comment: http://lesscss.org/#nesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided:

```
.user-images {
  // some CSS here
  
  .user-images {
    // some more CSS here
  }
}
```

which is written in LESS, will be compiled to this CSS code:

```
.user-images {
  // some CSS here
}

.user-images .user-images {
    // some more CSS here
}
```

In this way, LESS allows you to write code which is more "hierarchical" and easier to read than its CSS counterpart.

See [here](http://lesscss.org/#nesting) an example.

So when you moved out the inner `.user-images` you have broke everything because that would have been compiled to:

```
.user-images {
  // some CSS here
}

.user-images {
    // some more CSS here
}
```

which has a different semantic from the original code:

- with the original version, you are styling `.user-images` elements and `.user-images` elements which are inside other `.user-images` elements;
- with the last one you are simply re-defining the style of `.user-images` elements

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question. He asked about the code he wrote above and not the code you wrote down.

Comment: @DeniJ. I've updated my answer by adding an explanation of the semantic of that LESS code.

Comment: That's fine, but as far as I understood, the code of the asker is written in CSS and not in LESS. Therefore your answer won't help him out. If it does, then the question should be edited.

Comment: @DeniJ.no, the question clearly says that the code is written in LESS. See the last line of the question: `To note is that all the code is written in LESS and compiled to CSS.`

Comment: Read the first 2 sentences... The original code is written in LESS. But the compiled code he posted is written in CSS!

Comment: @Riccardo understood it correctly. I will edit the question so that it is not confusing anymore. Sorry.

Comment: I am aware of nesting, I was apparently confused by the fact that the same class name is used for the nested class.